# Editing Figure Legends - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have created a plot using ggplot to graph different responses to a drug combination.  One thing I am trying to do is to change the legends from "0" and "1" to "partial response" and "stable disease respectively.  I have tried the following code but I keep getting the error:

```
scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Partial Response", "Stable Disease"))
```

"Error in f(...) : argument "values" is missing, with no default"

Here is my original code:

```
ggplot(data = mdcf_plot, aes(x=reorder(DMP.ID, -OS), y=OS, fill = factor(Best.Response))) 
+ ylim(0,50) + ylab("Overall Survival (months)") + xlab("Response by DMP ID") 
+ theme_classic() + ggtitle("Overall Survival in Patients Treated with XYZ (n=11)") 
+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 
+ geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.4) + guides(fill = guide_legend(title 
= "Best Response"))
```

How can I adjust the scale_fill_code to edit these labels?

Answer (score 1):

Use `scale_fill_discrete` instead. For example

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, fill=factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_tile() + 
    scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("four","five","six","eight"))
```

Or add the values to your scale_fill_manual()

```
scale_fill_manual(values 0:1, labels = c("Partial Response", "Stable Disease"))
```

but that's really only for when you want to specify the colors yourself which you don't seem to want to do.